# In Laravel 5.5, how to get the Job ID after we dispatch a job to the job queue?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Until Laravel 5.4, the `dispatch()` method returned the queue job id.

```
$job = (new JobClass())->onQueue('queuename');
$jobId = dispatch($job);

dd($jobId); // prints the job id
```

In 5.5, it returns a `PendingDispatch` object, which does not seem to have a method to retrieve the job id.

I've already tried with `dispatch_now()`, but it executes the job immediately and synchronously, while I want it to be executed in the background.

Comment: `$job->id` or `job['id']`?

Comment: None of these work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After opening an issue at Laravel github, the solution was to use:

```
app(\Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher::class)->dispatch($job)
```

instead of

```
dispatch($job)
```

Answer (score 6):

You might also consider using `DispatchesJobs` trait:

```
class MyClassName()
{
    use DispatchesJobs;

    ....

    $job = (new JobClass())->onQueue('queuename');

    $jobId = $this->dispatch($job);
```

Comment: This worked for me in Laravel 7.  Very happy to have found a working solution.  Note that I had to add this line near the top of the file: use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;

Answer (score -1):

alexeydemin Code works as intended.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).